# Layered Images in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, gif

I need to layer two images (transparent gifs) in a report in SSRS 2008.  Has anyone ever done this?

Thanks for your replies!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to layer images in SSRS, using the z-index property of images. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275080%28SQL.80%29.aspx